# Need to implement highchart drill down in flutter app

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter.

I want to implement high chart with drill down.

Can anyone suggest, is it possible or not?

I found some examples, but I got the simple one (not drilldown option)

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
dependencies:
  high_chart: ^1.2.0
```

Then

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:high_chart/high_chart.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  static const _chart_data = '''{
      title: {
          text: 'Combination chart'
      },
      xAxis: {
          categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums']
      },
      labels: {
          items: [{
              html: 'Total fruit consumption',
              style: {
                  left: '50px',
                  top: '18px',
                  color: ( // theme
                      Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                      Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
                  ) || 'black'
              }
          }]
      },
      series: [{
          type: 'column',
          name: 'Jane',
          data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
      }, {
          type: 'column',
          name: 'John',
          data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
      }, {
          type: 'column',
          name: 'Joe',
          data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
      }, {
          type: 'spline',
          name: 'Average',
          data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33],
          marker: {
              lineWidth: 2,
              lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
              fillColor: 'white'
          }
      }, {
          type: 'pie',
          name: 'Total consumption',
          data: [{
              name: 'Jane',
              y: 13,
              color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // Jane's color
          }, {
              name: 'John',
              y: 23,
              color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // John's color
          }, {
              name: 'Joe',
              y: 19,
              color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2] // Joe's color
          }],
          center: [100, 80],
          size: 100,
          showInLegend: false,
          dataLabels: {
              enabled: false
          }
        }]
    }''';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('High Chart Example App'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: HighCharts(
            data: _chart_data,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It will shows all graphs on single time. not in drill down.